# Why event target isnt call a single element

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, events, drag, mousedown

I use event.target but if when i do bold for selected element with toggleClass. When i was click other elements they are all change. But my mousedown event is didnt just interest with single target ?

```
  function tik(xs){
       $.each(['bold', 'italic', 'right', 'left', 'center'], function(index, elem) {

            var x = xs; // e.target or drag event for this variable becomes to ui.helper

              if($(x).is('.drag') || $(x).is('.drags') ){

                  if($(x).hasClass(elem))
                      $(`.fa-${elem}`).addClass('selected');
                  else
                      $(`.fa-${elem}`).removeClass('selected');


                  if(index <= 1 ) { // bold and italic is 0-1 , left,r... 2-3-4

                      $(`.fa-${elem}`).click(function() {

                          $(x).toggleClass(`${elem}`);
                          $(`.fa-${elem}`).toggleClass('selected');


                      });
                  } else {
                      $(`.fa-align-${elem}`).click(function() {
                          $(x).toggleClass(`${elem}`);
                          $(`.fa-align-${elem}`).toggleClass('selected');

                      });
                  }
              }
              // $(x).addClass('parlak') // kontrol gelmeli
       });
  }
```

How i find cause to this problem ? I tried a lot but i dont find.
If a connect that with drag event, good works but this time not to be realtime and need do it dragging for seen

[I captured a video for show you](https://youtu.be/oYH0cZrm3so)

I know here is code all suck like sphagetti. But i coulndt do it. I was try lot of thing. Much more thing changed when i was working

Here is have a simplification status

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e,i) {
   // tik(e)

  var lastClicked;
  if($(e.target).is('.drag') || $(e.target).is('.drags')  ){
    lastClicked = e.target;
  }
  $('.fa-bold').click(function(){
        $(lastClicked).toggleClass('bold');
  })

});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not see any `event.target` elements.

Comment: Also what is `x`?

Comment: You are welcome,thanks. X variable is e.target in function.

Comment: I was try with drag in and mousedown. I edited it.